# PHP Form - incorrect

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

had a quick question, ive been using a php form for a long time now and its always worked however when im using it this time no email is ever coming through, did i occidentally change something and just keep missing it?

```
<div class="large-6 columns" data-equalizer-watch>

       <?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $from = 'From: test Website';
   $to = 'my email here';
   $subject = 'New email from website';

   $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

   if ($_POST['submit']) {
       if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
       echo '<p>Message Sent Successfully!</p>';
       } else {
       echo '<p>Ah! Try again, please?</p>';
       }
   }
?>   
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <label>Your Name:</label>
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name"><br><br>
            <label>Your Contact Number:</label>
            <input name="contact" placeholder="Contact Number"><br><br>
            <label>Your Email:</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"><img src="img/send.png"></button>
        </form>

  </div><!-- relative -->

  <div class="large-6 columns" data-equalizer-watch>
     <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>Your Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </form>
  </div>
```

for the `$to` i did use my proper gmail account. contact form is on my index page.

Comment: Have you bothered checking your server's mail log to see what happened to the email after PHP handed it over? Did you check your account's spam folder on the receiving end?

Comment: Your `message` textarea is in another `form` so it will never submit, your `$from` does not contain a valid e-mail address.

Comment: aside from the second form, everything else is fine? checked with my isp, apparently there was a configuration issue on there firewall, so ill check its working properly later when im home. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to mail before `if statement`  in your code

```
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
      mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from);
      if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
         echo '<p>Message Sent Successfully!</p>';
      } else {
         echo '<p>Ah! Try again, please?</p>';
      }
   }
```